# Down sampling times series data in oracle

Tags: oracle, web, statistics

I have a data set of time series data I would like to display on a line graph.  The data is currently stored in an oracle table and the data is sample at 1 point / second.  The ask is to  plot the data over a 6 month period of time.  Is there a way to down sample the data inside of oracle (this can be done in various charts, but I don't want to move the data over the network).  For example, if a query returns 10K points, how can I down sample this to 1K points and still have the line graph and keep the visual characteristics (peaks/valley)of the 10K points.

Comment: How sophisticated are you trying to get?  If there is 1 second in the middle of the data set that is a huge outlier but everything else is basically a flat line, would it be acceptable to, at least potentially, skip that point and render a flat line?  Or do the "visual characteristics" include all outliers?  What defines an outlier for you?  The more you downsample the more you'll affect things like the best fit line to the data set-- how big an affect you will have, though, is difficult to say a priori.

Comment: Is there a way to make the degree of the outlier configurable?  For example, can I say any single point that is 20% (this is the variable) above/below the previous point (or n points???) then that point is significant.  The key is the outliers, meaning the users don't care about a 'flat line' over six months.  The interesting data are the outliers.  Once the outlier is identified, then the user can zoom in on that area and the sampling rate is reduce (ie, less sampling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My advice is to display the values averaged over time intervals, and also make it possible to zoom in and display a shorter range averaged over shorter intervals, and to display the raw data (no average) when the time range is short enough.

For example:

- when time range is greater than 1 month, average by days
- when time range is less than 1 month and greater than 1 day, average by hours
- when time range is less than 1 day and greater than 1 hour, average by minutes
- when time range is less than 1 hour, raw data only (no average)

By the way, I'm pretty sure you can tell Oracle to do the averaging in the SQL query as a clause in your SELECT statement. I don't know the syntax.